# Crear etiqueta Html + Css

Tags: html, css, angular

Saludos estoy intentando agregar una etiqueta de porcentaje a un boton pero no logro hacerlo, agradeceria mucho su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así deberia quedar los botones con sus etiquetas que el valor de porcentaje es dinamico

al momento he intentado esto

```
<div>
<span class="etiquetaOferta">{{redondeo(itemi.porcentajeDescuento)}}%</span>
<img class="imageOferta" src='../../../../../../assets/images/icons/etiqueta-oferta.svg'>

<button>
    07:20 - 07:40
</button>
```

con el css

```
.imageOferta {
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
margin-left: 13%;
margin-top: 1px;
}

span.etiquetaOferta {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

pero al hacer eso se desborda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas Tardes, puedes poner lo que haz intentado o un ejemplo de lo que llevas al momento, ya que todo puede variar dependiendo de lo que tienes actualmente.

Comment: ya lo edité con lo que he intentado...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar `position: absolute;` para ubicar la etiqueta dentro del button. La forma del triangulo en la parte baja de la etiqueta se puede crear con [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after) agregando bordes transparentes.

```css
:root {
  --bg-btn: #2fcc71;
  --bg-tag: #171d49;
  --text-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.button {
  background-color: var(--bg-btn);
  color: var(--text-color);
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button .etiquetaOferta {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg-tag);
  color: var(--text-color);
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

.button .etiquetaOferta:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 6px var(--bg-tag);
  border-left: solid 15px transparent;
  border-right: solid 15px transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
      <span class="etiquetaOferta">20%</span>
      07:20 - 07:40
</button>
```

Comment: justo lo que buscaba, te lo agradezco mucho...

Answer (score 1):

Una solución de mi parte sería poner todo dentro del botón.
Teniendo en cuenta que estás usando bootstrap y una imágen como etiqueta, Quedaría así:

```css
 

.btn.etiquetaOferta {
 padding-right: calc(.375rem * 2 + 30px);
}

.btn .imageOferta {
 display: block;
 position:absolute;
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
 top:0;
 right: .375rem;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: url(../../../../../../assets/images/icons/etiqueta-oferta.svg);  
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">   
 </head>
 <body>
  <button class="btn btn-success etiquetaOferta">
   <span class="imageOferta"></span>
   botón de lo que sea
  </button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Acá no se ve la imágen `.svg` porque puse la misma ruta de tu archivos local

Comment: muchas gracias muy buen aporte...